# A container is a database server. How to ask it's Dockerfile to complete its construction after that container has started?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using a `postgis/postgis` Docker image to set a database server for my application.

1. The database server must have a tablespace created, then a database.
2. Then each time another application will start from another container, it will run a `Liquibase` script that will update the database schema (create tables, index...) when needed.

On a terminal, to prepare the database container, I'm running these commands :

```sh
# Run a naked Postgis container
sudo docker run --name ecoemploi-postgis 
     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres 
     -d -v /data/comptes-france:/data/comptes-france postgis/postgis

# Send 'bash level' commands to create the directory for the tablespace
sudo docker exec -it ecoemploi-postgis 
     bin/sh -c 'mkdir /tablespace && chown postgres:postgres /tablespace'
```

Then to complete my step 1, I have to run SQL statements to create the tablespace in a `PostGIS` point of view, and create the database by a `CREATE DATABASE`.

I connect myself, manually, under the `psql` of my container :

```sh
sudo docker exec -it ecoemploi-postgis bin/sh 
     -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" 
     -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'
```

And I run manally these commands :

```sh
CREATE TABLESPACE data LOCATION '/tablespace';
CREATE DATABASE comptesfrance TABLESPACE data;
exit
```

But I would like to have a container created from a single `Dockerfile` having done all the needed work. The difficulty is that it has to be done in two parts :

1. One before the container is started. (creating directories, granting them user:group).
2. One after it is started for the first time : declaring the tablespace and creating the base. If I understand well the base image I took, it should be done after an entrypoint `docker-entrypoint.sh` has been run ?

What is the good way to write a `Dockerfile` creating a container having done all these steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PostGIS image](https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis) "is based on the official [postgres](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image", so it should be able to use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism.  Any files you put in that directory will be run the first time the database container is started.  [The `postgis` Dockerfile already uses this directory](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) to install the PostGIS extensions into the default database.

That means you can put your build-time setup directly into the Dockerfile, and copy the startup-time script into that directory.

```sh
FROM postgis/postgis:12-3.0
RUN mkdir /tablespace && chown postgres:postgres /tablespace
COPY createdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/20-createdb.sql
# Use default ENTRYPOINT/CMD from base image
```

For the particular setup you describe, this may not be necessary.  Each database runs in an isolated filesystem space and starts with an empty data directory, so there's not a specific need to create an alternate data directory; Docker style is to just run multiple databases if you need isolated storage.  Similarly, the base `postgres` image will create a database for you at first start (named by the `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable).

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a container, your Dockerfile must be functional and completed.
you must enter the queries in a bash file and in the last line you have to enter an ENTRYPOINT with this bash script

Comment: Please give concrete answers and examples to the question